# How to use TSimpleGraph component?

Tags: c++, delphi, diagram, vcl

I have downloaded and installed [TSimpleGraph](http://www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-components/simplegraph/) component but cannot really understand how to use it. I've checked the demo but it is too complexed for me and in Delphi (I use C++ Builder) to be able to dissect what I need.

What I am trying is to create two rectangles that are connect with an arrow line. Rectangles should be able to move when user drags them and the arrow should move accordingly (pointing from one rectangle to another). If someone could provide me with this example (Delphi or C++ Builder) I believe I could figure out the rest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't think that would work. You can show you attempts and ask abut specific errors in them. But you as kfor someone to teach you, to make for you a brand new tutorial, not too complex and not too shallow, customized for your ease of reading. I do not think that would work out here. http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried

Comment: I specified what I need. I don't need a tutorial, just two rectangles connected with arrow line. I cannot show my work since I don't know how to even start and cannot find anything else online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Node: TRectangularNode;
  Link: TGraphLink;
begin
  FGraph := TSimpleGraph.Create(Self);
  FGraph.SetBounds(10, 10, 400, 400);
  FGraph.BeginUpdate;
  Node := TRectangularNode.Create(FGraph);
  Node.SetBounds(25, 25, 100, 50);
  Node := TRectangularNode.Create(FGraph);
  Node.SetBounds(200, 200, 50, 100);
  Link := TGraphLink.Create(FGraph);
  Link.Link(FGraph.Objects[0], FGraph.Objects[1]);
  FGraph.EndUpdate;
  FGraph.Parent := Self;
end;
```